# Div and CSS: spacers the same between divs in major div? I.e spacers the same between yellow 2x3 boxes with red background

Tags: css, html

I want the left (blue header/footer, green sides, red middle thing with 6 inside boxes), I got the right i.e. horizontal things with this code [here](http://pastie.org/5420057).

[image]

How can I make the yellow boxes as 3x2 with the red background and green/blue sides? How can I do this layout [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/724c0.png) in other words? When I change the layout a bit, I usually find out that the spacers between the yellow things are not equal -- how can make it with equal spacers?

Comment: why not use a layout framework like http://960.gs/ or http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: well i only suggested them because i thought if you are building a site its better to use these frameworks since they are easy to use\maintain and are well documented

Comment: @keshav moved the framework -thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520712/css-html-generator-designer-built-for-ipad-without-typing-anything), the 960 actually sounds quite clever but trying to find some fast way to do it with iPad -- otherwise I will type it faster on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you on the right track

```
<html>
<style>
        .block{
                background-color:yellow;
                height:20px;
                width:300px;
                border:20px;
                display:inline;
                float: left;
                margin:10px;
        }
        #document{
                background-color:green;
        }
        #pitches{
                background-color:red;
                margin:auto;
                overflow:auto;
                width:700px;
                height:300px;
        }
        #header, div#footer{
                background-color:blue;
                height:200px;
                margin:auto;
                overflow:auto;
                width:900px;
        }
</style>

<body>
        <div id='document'>
                <div id='header'></div>
                <div id='pitches'>
                        <div class='block'></div>
                        <div class='block'></div>
                        <div class='block'></div>
                        <div class='block'></div>
                </div>
                <div id='footer'></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...`"display:inline;"`: could you explain it? I usually select them by random, any good tutorial about different options?

Comment: hey here is some documentation on [css display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) you should also look at [floats](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Comment: ...err but block -thing also works in display, what is really the difference?

Comment: okay so
Block
Takes up the full width available, with a new line before and after (display:block;)
Inline
Takes up only as much width as it needs, and does not force new lines (display:inline;)

Comment: Suppose the pitches has width of 1000px. Yellow block' -box has width like 400px. Now I create them like, http://pastie.org/5422366, how can I get equal sized spacers in sides and middle thing? I.e. (1000-800)/3=200/3=66 pixels is on the left, middle and right.

Answer (score 0):

using with ul li with

```
ul:background:red   
li:background:yellow
```

will be usefull :

http://jsfiddle.net/QVX7V/